# how to run javascript code in android studio?

Tags: javascript, android

I have an android app,, inside the app I get a javascript code and I need to compile it (the running result).. 
+ I want to add other commands such that for instance for/while/if commands run using the regular js compiler but another commands such that BLABLA command which is unrecognized by the js language (compiler as well). I want to custom run it from another file where is defined all the "other commands"

thank you ;)

String generatedCode="var a;\n a=0;\n while(a!=3){\n a=a+1; \n BLABLABLA myOwnParameters; \n }

Comment: Building a complete JavaScript interpreter from scratch is beyond the scope of this site. There are complete textbooks on writing compilers.

Comment: You can write your server to do it. Send the code to the server run it on the server get the result.